# Android uiautomator - working with with bars

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

While trying Android uiautomator utility i face some problem working with bars. (such as bottom bar that display time, wifi status, battery etc...)

The issue is that the bottom bar seems to be not part of the display and when trying to click on it (using uidevice method click(x,y) ), i am getting return value of false - , clicking on pixel above it works just fine (with return value of true)

when using the uiviewer utility clicking on the bar does not update the right pane, e.g: the "display" does not seem to include the bar at all.

is there a known issue with bars and uiautomator ?
can bar be test/interact using uiautomator ?

Thanks in advance, Gal.

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you are trying to do, it is unclear at the moment. Are you trying to get detailed wifi, battery, etc. data?

Answer (score 1):

My initial investigations match your findings - neither the top notification bar (that displays the time, status indicators e.g. battery, network connectivity, etc) or the bottom bar with icons for the soft keys (back, home, etc.) are available in `uiautomationviewer` despite being contained in a FrameLayout.

(Note: I'm checking on a Nexus 4 phone, and a Nexus 7 tablet. Some tablet devices have the notification bar at the bottom of the screen e.g. my A500)

Based on my preliminary findings UI Automator will not be suitable. Perhaps `monkeyrunner` would be more suitable e.g. see the following question and answer [Can monkeyrunner interact with android notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259760/can-monkeyrunner-interact-with-android-notifications)

Comment: Thank you Julian, I will check it out.

Comment: When i tried to use the monkeyrunner touch method with panel coordiate it seem to work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the good news. Would you mind 'accepting' my answer so that others know it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

When i tried to use the monkeyrunner touch method with a coordinate locate inside the bar it work fine.

I guess this is something that Google will fix in future releases in the UiAutomator.

Thanks again,

Gal.